# postgresSQL: column doesn't exist, when trying to insert into table

Tags: sql, postgresql, string-constant

when I run this in terminal:

```
INSERT INTO signup (username, user_password) VALUES("John", "dqw1");
```

It gives me: ERROR:  column "John" does not exist.

What could be the problem here? this doesn't even make sense, the column name is username. "John" is just a value, it shouldn't exist before.

Comment: Use single quotes instead of double quotes

Answer (score 4):

The issue is with the double quotes - postgres is interpreting them as "delimited identifiers" (i.e. the name of an object, such as a column in a table).

So instead of this:

```
INSERT INTO signup (username, user_password) VALUES("John", "dqw1");
```

Do this:

```
INSERT INTO signup (username, user_password) VALUES('John', 'dqw1');
```

Comment: This is a FAQ - closing it as a duplicate would have been more useful. This behavior is dictated by the SQL standard.